# Missing logs in current folder

Tags: bro, zeek

I am using security onion image 16.04.5.6.
I am new to Bro and according to [this](https://github.com/Security-Onion-Solutions/security-onion/wiki/Bro) in current folder I should be albe to find http.logs file. However I only see :

```
loaded_scripts.log  reporter.log  stderr.log
packet_filter.log   stats.log     stdout.log
```

I have found in FAQ [here](https://www.zeek.org/documentation/faq.html#why-isn-t-zeek-producing-the-logs-i-expect-a-note-about-checksums) and when I use Bro as a Command-Line Utility I provide -C parameter I am able to see the http.log

But when I use BroCtl the http.log is missing I have tried to change

```
redef ignore_checksums = T;
```

but this option is missing in my local.bro file.

And the last FAQ solution seems to be working

```
sudo ethtool --offload enp0s3 rx off tx off
Cannot get device udp-fragmentation-offload settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device udp-fragmentation-offload settings: Operation not supported
Actual changes:
tx-checksumming: off
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
    tx-tcp-segmentation: off [requested on]
```

However in my current folder I cannot find http.log.

Any ideas what I can do now or whast am I missing?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that HTTP traffic is passing the sensor?  Bro will only create logs for traffic that it sees.

Comment: You're also not seeing other basic logs, such as conn.log. Check the existing logs (reporter.log, stderr.log, stdout.log) to see if they reveal any clues?

Comment: I have reinstalled the SO and I have realized that I have set a wrong network interface as a sniffing sensor. (HTTP traffic wasn't passing that sensor)

Comment: Based on the comments from @roffensive, this should be closed.